# What does fugacity mean in the context of geology?

Tags: geology, geochemistry, planetary-science, mantle, moon

I am reading about water in the Lunar mantle, however it mentions fugacity a lot. What does it mean in this context?

Comment: This is not my area of expertise, but do these help: [Fugacity: definitions, concepts, and geology](https://www.geol.umd.edu/facilities/lmdr/fugacity.html) & [Introduction to oxygen fugacity and its petrologic importance](https://pubs.geoscienceworld.org/msa/rimg/article/25/1/1/87287/Introduction-to-oxygen-fugacity-and-its-petrologic)?

Comment: From various online dictionaries. Fugacious: ephemeral , temporary , transient , transitory, fleeting, tending to disappear, unenduring volatile, evanescent, momentary.

Comment: It might help others if you could provide a link to the item you have been reading.

Answer (score 1):

'Fugacity' is effectively the equivalent of chemical activity, but for gases. Fugacity relates to the partial pressure of a particular volatile component of a system in the same way that chemical activity relates to the concentration of a given chemical phase.

Most often in geology, this will refer to 'fugacity of oxygen (*f*O<sub>2</sub>)' in a system - this is effectively a measure of how reactive oxygen is, and thus how oxidized a given system will be, usually with respect to the minerals that are stable in them.

At temperatures that most mantle processes operate on, aqueous fluid phases generally exist in a supercritical state, which we also apply the concept of fugacity to. So, if the text you are reading states something about 'fugacity of H<sub>2</sub>O', then it is likely referring to the reactivity of supercritical water vapor in the lunar mantle system.